# How to prevent users from creating custom client apps?

Tags: rest, security, jwt, architecture

Imaging, I have a web-app called **CoolApp** that accesses its server via JWT access+refresh tokens. What's stopping the user from grabbing these tokens and then creating their own ***Custom*CoolApp**?

For example, what's stopping me from creating a completely custom app for, say, Reddit, making a request to `/login`, getting JWTs and using them inside my custom app?

Comment: Technically? Probably nothing. Legally? That’s another thing and outside of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Users can only grab jwt token if the provider of the token is public endpoint open to all. If you have control over the endpoint providing jwt token, you can setup basic CORS policies so that only your app will be whitlested and accessible to the endpoints.
Here is the sample example for CORS settings
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-cors-next-js-handle-cross-origin-requests/

Comment: But CORS only exist in browsers, isn't it? What about an Android app?

Comment: CORS policy get handled by server where you are deploying endpoint and only deals with header values of incoming requests.So no matter which platform you are using, as long as correct header values are reaching server , connection is allowed. Refer the diagram in this to understand basic flow https://laniak-keynote.netlify.app/article?topic=Cross+Origin+Resource+Sharing

Comment: Also apart fro. Origin, you can also define specific acceptable credentials or headers on server side for CORS